# stream buffer (cin, getline, etc)

Tags: c++, iostream

Is there a way to have the user input a line of characters to the stream buffer and then store them in different variables (of different types)?

For example, the user writes this sum of fractions:

```
1/5 + 2/7
```

I have 5 variables:

```
int numerator1, denominator1, numerator2, denominator2; char operat;
```

and after doing a fancy piece of code that i don't know, in the end, the variables will have stored the following

```
numerator1 = 1
denominator1 = 5
operat = +
numerator2 = 2
denominator2 = 7
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to make it more general and work on a full free formula. Look for the shunting yard algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely use the ASTs as they would help you parse the errors. But if you are looking for a simple parsing capabilities you can consider using sscanf. PS: Posting it as an answer due to reputation problem.

```
#include<cstring>                                                                       
#include<cstdio>                                                                        
#include<iostream>                                                                      
using namespace std;                                                                    

int main()                                                                              
{                                                                                       
    char s[1024];                                                                   
    scanf("%s", s);                                                                 

    int n1, n2, dn1, dn2;                                                           
    char op1, op2, op3;                                                             
    sscanf(s, "%d%c%d%c%d%c%d", &n1, &op1, &dn1, &op2, &n2, &op3, &dn2);            

    cout<<"\n"<<n1<<" "<<op1<<" "<<dn1<<" "<<op2<<" "<<n2<<" "<<op3<<" "<<dn2<<endl;
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of the percentage sign?

Comment: they are format specifiers in C, %s for string, %c for char and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure of the specific algorithms, to attain this functionality, But i can suggest the following.

instead of using multiple variables, Take an integer array and a character array. 
Take the input from the user in a string.

- Loop through the character string and perform the following.

  If, the value at current index is a num, Iterate counter until you
  find a space or an operator (+/-*)

  Extract the sub sting of it and store it in int array at the
  corresponding index.

  if the value at an index is an operator, store it in char array.